# Stop focus on EditText when keyboard is hidden

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm from iOS development and new in Android app making, something looks really strange to me in Android, why EditText stay focused when keyboard is hidden ??

I've tried to set a OnFocusChangeListener on my EditText but this is not working when the keyboard hide, the listener isn't called.

I've also tried to detect keyboard hiding with a onChangeListener but it doesn't work.. (only with hard keyboard apparently).

```
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // not called when keyboard hides
        }
    });
```

I've been looking for a while and I only found answer for stopping focus at first launch but that's not what I'm looking for..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Okay, kind of this

```
  private void setUpEtxFocusListener() {
    etx.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                if ((LOG_DEBUG)) Log.d(TAG, "etx : GOT Focus");

            } else {
                if ((LOG_DEBUG)) Log.d(TAG, "etx : LOST Focus");

            }
        }
    });
```

and when clicked outside, etx will lose focus and you hide the keyboard

```
 //this will trigger etx  setOnFocusChangeListener -  onFocus change() - NO FOCUS clause
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View v = getCurrentFocus();
        if (v instanceof EditText) {
            Rect outRect = new Rect();
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
            if (!outRect.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
                v.clearFocus();
               // just an utility class to hide.
                UtilExtra.hideKeyboard(this);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what if i'm hiding the keyboard with the return button ? onBackPressed isn't called when I just press back button to hide keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this code and your focus will be gone

```
editText.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

To catch keyboard's open/close event use this code:

```
    //...
    private int layoutSize = 0;
    private boolean isKeyboardVisible = false;
    //...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setKeyboardOpenListener();
    }
    //...
    private void setKeyboardOpenListener() {
            View activityRootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
                if (activityRootView.getHeight() + Util.getStatusBarHeight(this) >= layoutSize) {
                    layoutSize = activityRootView.getHeight();
                    if (isKeyboardVisible) {
                        isKeyboardVisible = false;
                        onKeyboardClose();
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!isKeyboardVisible) {
                        isKeyboardVisible = true;
                        onKeyboardOpen();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    //...
    public static int getStatusBarHeight(Context context) {
            int result = 0;
            int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use editText.clearFocus() and editText.setCursorVisible(false) both methods, It may helps you.

Comment: Fine, but what about keyboard visibility event?

Comment: on focus of edit text , kindly setCursorVisible(true)